# How can I make that the BottomTabNavigator not to cover the scroll view?

Tags: react-native, realm

[image]

How can I make that the scroll view to fit the screen good?

```
        return(
                    <ScrollView scrollEnabled contentContainerStyle = {{marginBottom: 'auto'}}>
                        {this.state.bills.map(bill => {
                            return(
                                <Bill bill = {bill} key = {bill.id} />
                            )
                        })}
                    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cover your scroll view inside an view with {flex:1},
this helped me in my app

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main}>
        <ScrollView scrollEnabled contentContainerStyle = {{marginBottom: 'auto'}}>
                        {this.state.bills.map(bill => {
                            return(
                                <Bill bill = {bill} key = {bill.id} />
                            )
                        })}
                    </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
   flex: 1   
  }
});
```

Comment: this hide my components in the ScrollView

Comment: try `style = {{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}` for scroll view

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the scroll view with a SafeAreaView like the following:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
  <ScrollView ...>...</ScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```